# How do you add a file to a new repository on github?

Tags: github

I've created a new repo on github, and while my old repos have a "Create new file" button,  my new repo does not.  How do I get my new repo to have this button?

Here's one that has the button:
https://github.com/volumetricsteve/Litmus-Maps

The new one does not:
https://github.com/volumetricsteve/HFM

I can't work out what the functional difference is between them that makes it so I can use the webgui to add files to one and not the other.

Comment: Are you also using Git locally?

Comment: I've never used the CLI for it because I've never needed to before.  So...I'm not sure what 'locally' is but I'm guessing not.

Comment: The CLI is the normal way of adding files to a repository, at least in my experience.  If you have access to the CLI, you can just add whatever files you want and then push to GitHub.

Comment: I know it is, but I've always been able to do this: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8fdc501d6746c307ada3d168e5db7b8d1b12cd75/687474703a2f2f636c2e6c792f4c4c65302f6e65772d66696c652e6a7067  but I just don't have that button in my new repo.

Comment: Then this could be a permissions issue of some kind.

Comment: I've thrown in the towel and contacted github support.  I'll post the answer back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From GitHub support:

"If you create a new repo with no files at all then it assumes you are going to push an existing project up and so doesn't initialize the git repo itself.

git itself can't show empty folders, which also complicates things.

The easiest way around it to tick the "Initialize this repository with a README" box, or select a license or .gitignore file to initialise the repo with.

You may have to delete that one and recreate it."
- @danayel
GitHub Support

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, the [second repo `volumetricsteve/HFM`](https://github.com/volumetricsteve/HFM) which does not have the button also has no files, no commit, no branch.

It is an empty repository.

Try to clone it, and make at least one empty commit, and push it, before trying to look for that button.

```
git clone https://github.com/volumetricsteve/HFM.git
cd HFM
git commit --allow-empty -m "first initial empty commit"
git push -u origin master
```

You can also initialize the repo through the GUI: see "[Creating files on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/licensing-a-repository/#applying-a-license-to-a-repository-with-an-existing-license)"*

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/repository-license-picker.png]

(for quickly adding a README, license or `.gigignore` file)

Once the repo is initialize with one file (meaning one commit in master branch), the "Create new file" button will be visible.

---

> My needs are extremely simple and my "projects" are generally a single file.

Consider using a **[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/)** (see "[About Gist](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/)"): each gist is its [own Git repo](https://help.github.com/articles/forking-and-cloning-gists/).

Comment: While you're not wrong, I'm trying to do everything through their webgui.  My needs are *extremely* simple and my "projects" are generally a single file.

Comment: @Volumetricsteve Sire, GUI works too: I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: That's really interesting.  Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Volumetricsteve I meant "Sure, GUI works too", not "Sire, GUI works too" ;)

Comment: @VonC, missing ".git" at the end of `git clone` url.